# Apollo Graphql fetchMore, updateQuery does not update state

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm currently trying to implement pagination on my `posts`.
Using Apollo graphql here is my useQuery

```
const { data: postsData, fetchMore } = useQuery(POSTS_BY_USER_DRAFT, {
fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
variables: {
  user: user.id,
  start: 0,
  limit: limit
},
onCompleted: () => {
  setTotal(postsData[model].meta.pagination.total)
}})
```

and here is my onClick handler for fetching more `posts`

```
const loadMorePosts = async () => {
const nextStart = start + limit
setStart(nextStart);
await fetchMore({
  variables: {
    user: user.id,
    offset: nextStart,
    limit: limit,
  },
  updateQuery: (prevResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
    if (!fetchMoreResult) {
      return prevResult
    }
    const prevData = prevResult[model].data
    const moreData = fetchMoreResult[model].data

    fetchMoreResult[model].data = [...prevData, ...moreData]
    // fetchMoreResult[model].data = [...moreData]
    return fetchMoreResult
  },
})}
```

My queries are successful as I do get correctly the data, however `postsData` does not get updated

[NOTICED]: If I switch `fetchMoreResult[model].data = [...prevData, ...moreData]` for
`fetchMoreResult[model].data = [...moreData]`  my `postsData` does get updated.

I have tried `return { ...fetchMoreResult }` and multiple ways of returning data fearing an immutability/comparaison issue but it does not seem to do the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but setting a fetchPolicy for Apollo will do the job

```
const client = new ApolloClient({


link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      Publication: {
        merge: true,
      },
      Post: {
        merge: true,
      },
    },
  }),
  defaultOptions: defaultOptions,
})
```

Comment: I had the same issue using MongoDB Realm and your answer helped me realize that I needed a typePolicy for each custom resolver that made use of fetchMore or refetch.

Comment: This is a requirement of Apollo's InMemoryCache: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#typepolicy-fields

Just wanted to share the why :)